# Position geom_text labels correclty when using factes AND color in the aes argument

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes, geom-text

I have a three-way interaction, and I created a figure with facets and the color argument in the aesthetic part.
I would like to annotate boxplot with the number of replicates, or the mean, or tukey letters, but I fail always when I use the color argument as the labels are all centered.
How can I correctly position the labels so that they are not clumped in the center?

Here is some example data:

```
location = rep(c("Bank", "Crop"),each=45)
treat = rep(c("field" ,"30","40"),30) 
value = c(1:90) 
storage = rep(c("fresh", "frozen"),45)
df = data.frame(location, treat, storage,value)
```

The information for the geom_text

```
test.dat <- df %>% 
  group_by(location,treat, storage) %>% 
  summarise(mean.h20 = round(mean(value,na.rm=TRUE),0), 
            total = n())
```

The plot:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = storage, y=value, fill=treat))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=treat), position=position_dodge(.9))+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=18, size=3, color="orange")+
  labs(x="Condition", y="Value")+
  facet_grid(~location)+
  geom_text(data = test.dat, aes(y=0, label = mean.h20))
```

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Add `position_dodge` to `geom_text` as well as already using it in `geom_point`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = storage, y=value, fill=treat))+
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=treat), position=position_dodge(.9))+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=18, size=3, color="orange")+
  labs(x="Condition", y="Value")+
  facet_grid(~location)+
  geom_text(data = test.dat, aes(y=0, label = mean.h20),
            position = position_dodge(width=0.9))
```

[image: ggplot boxplot with labels dodged]